# Vue.js - Computed property is not triggered when data is changing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, debouncing

I'm using `vue-js` and `element-ui` running on `dev-server` coming from `vue-cli` with the `webpack` template.

I'm trying to debounce the search value of a filterable input. In other words, I would like to `debounce` the `:filter-method` and getting the parameters `query` to do an `ajax` call

Here is the fiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/ffeohmk4/

**In that example there is no debounce yet.**

#### Problem

The function `getFinalList` is never triggered. I would assume since it is a `computed property`it should be triggered each time `this.searchValue` changes.

```
    var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        searchValue : '',
        filteredOptions : [],
        options: [{
          value: 'A',
          label: 'A'
        }, {
          value: 'B',
          label: 'B'
        }, {
          value: 'C',
          label: 'C'
        }, {
          value: 'D',
          label: 'D'
        }, {
          value: 'E',
          label: 'E'
        }],
        value8: ''
      }
    },
    computed : {
      getFinalList () {
      alert('getFinalList is called');
       this.filteredOptions = this.options.filter(option => {
          return option.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchValue.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        })
      }
    },
    methods : {
    setSearchInput (query) {this.searchValue = query}
    },
    created () {
    this.filteredOptions = this.options;
    }
  }
    var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
    new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: Isn't `el-select` a dropdown? Why are you debouncing a dropdown?

Comment: it is a select in which I can enter a value, to filter the rendered list. I don't want to do a `AJAX` call each time I hit the keyboard

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ffeohmk4/ I managed to creates another jsfiddled that might be simpler to understand. Here also, the computed property is not trigerred

Comment: Computed property must return something as a value. If you want to assign values to data props - use a `method`.

Comment: @leo It's never called because there is no reference to the computed property. https://jsfiddle.net/ffeohmk4/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working another example https://jsfiddle.net/ffeohmk4/2/

```
getFinalList () {
   return this.filteredOptions = this.options.filter(option => {
      return option.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchValue.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    })
  }



<el-select v-model="searchValue" filterable placeholder="Select" :filter-method="setSearchInput">
<el-option v-for="item in getFinalList" :key="item.value" :label="item.label" :value="item.value">
</el-option>
```

Comment: some explanations could help